# C++ typedef declaration

Tags: c++, typedef

Can you please explain what does the following line means?

```
typedef int (*Callback)(void * const param,int s)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that `Callback` is a new name for the type : pointer to a function returning an int and taking two parameters of type 'const pointer to void' and 'int'.

Given a function `f` :

```
int f(void * const param, int s)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

The `Callback` can be used to store a pointer to `f` :

```
Callback c = &f;
```

The function `f` can be later invoked through the pointer without directly referring to its name :

```
int result = c(NULL, 0);
```

At the point of the call, the name `f` does not appear.

Comment: and how can I implement this function?

Comment: @gln: it's a pointer to function, it usually meant to point of an existing function which matches the signature

Comment: Maybe you should add some code that shows how the callback c is called, to clear things up. :)

Answer (score 2):

It creates a new "alias" or name by which you can refer to pointers to functions that return `int` and take two parameters: a `void* const` and an int.  You can then create variables of that type, assign to them, invoke the function through them etc as in:

```
int fn(void * const param,int s) { ... }

Callback p;
p = fn;
int x = p(NULL, 38);
```

Note that `typedef`s do not really create new types... every equivalent typedef is resolved to the single real type for the purposes of overload resolution, template instantiation etc..

Comment: I do like the term alias here. I wish typedef had actually been called typealias (with typedef creating new types).

Comment: @Martin: that would be really good - have had to create `template <typename T, int N> class Wrapper {...};` and manually vary `N` often enough to simulate new 'T's.  Rounding that out, features to map from a "new type" back to the real underlying type, allow the programmer to specify whether there should be separate template instantiations or a shared one, and whether the types should be equivalent for matching function call parameters - but that's quite a bit of extra complexity!

Answer (score 2):

It declares a function type:

```
// Set up Callback as a type that represents a function pointer
typedef int (*Callback)(void * const param,int s);

// A function that matches the Callback type
int myFunction(void* const param,int s)
{
    // STUFF
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    // declare a variable and assign to it.
    Callback   funcPtr = &myFunction;
}
```